# Организация редактирования контента используя плагин Bootstrap-Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Всем привет.

Хочу на одном сайте упростить редактирование материала (новости) используя плагин [Bootstrap-Modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal).

В общем то сложного ничего там нет

```
var $modal = $('#ajax-modal');

$('.load-page').on('click', function(){
  // create the backdrop and wait for next modal to be triggered
  $('body').modalmanager('loading');

var page = $(this).data('page');

$modal.load('action_ajax.php?load_page='+page, '', function()
{
    $modal.modal();
});
});
```

В файле `action_ajax.php` получаю гетом `load_page` и делаю инклуд файла.
а в том файле уже (то же `get`) беру `news_id` и тянут данные новости из БД для редактирования.

Обычно я пользовался просто `$.ajax`, а тут `load`.

Вопрос в том, можно ли сделать так?

```
<a class="load-page" data-page="edit_news&news_id=4" data-toggle="modal" href="news.php?action=edit&news_id=4">Редактировать</a>
```

**data-page** - страница которую грузить

в **href** оставляю ссылку на случай, если какие-то проблемы с JS возникнут.

Может стоит отделить?
data-**page** - edit_news - какой файл инклудить

data-**params** - &news_id=4

В правильном направлении я иду в реализации этого всего?
Не вызовет ли проблем? У меня в opera, firefox, ie10, chrome... все корректно работает.

Буду благодарен за советы по реализации или поправки)

Comment: Сори за форматирование текста, никак не получается нормально переносы строк сделал. Делаю один энтер - строки в результате не переносит. Исправить нормально не получается.

Comment: @drop_off, обычно задают вопросы, если что-то не получается, а что же смутило вас, когда всё работает? )) Всё достаточно логично, поэтому проблем не должно возникать.

Comment: Я только разбираюсь. Мне важно понять в правильном ли направлении я иду. Не будет ли каких-то проблем с применением того, что сделал в будущем и т.д... Возможно я что-то упускаю или не знаю важного.
Получить рекомендации в данном случае при простом гуглении не получится) По этому и обращаюсь с вопросами сюда, надеясь получить совет))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения данных из БД достаточно .load() метода. Отличие .load() от $.get() в том, что 
можно взять только часть из полученных данных. Например, если из БД выгружается структура шаблона страницы и мы хотим получить только header страницы:

```
$('#load_into_me').load('templates/template1.html #header');
```

Comment: Ага. В доках это смотрел.
Я просто подумал, правильно ли использовать именно load в моей ситуации.

По поводу crud. В приведенной ранее ссылке вроде сложноватый вариант.
Мне бы в таком случае просто какой-то простенький, с массовым редактированием в таблице, постраничка и т.д... Сейчас ищу подобные.
Т.е. чтобы просто внедрить было. Спасибо.

Comment: Убрал ссылку потому что сомневался подойдет ли Вам гроцери крад для интеграции, но на всякий случай запощу еще раз.

 http://www.grocerycrud.com/

Посмотрите документацю - там как раз массовое редактирование, постраничка и всё довольно просто внедряется.