# Автоматизация процессов обработки AJAX запросов

Tags: ajax, php, классы

Всем привет.
Сори, если заголовок не очень подходит под вопросв. Просто кратко и лаконично описать его не получилось))

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205845/) задавал вопрос о ajax редактировании. В целом все работает замечательно.
Решил таким образом сделать не только новости, но и много чего еще.

Но возник вопрос вот какой.
За обработку AJAX запросов отвечает файл action_ajax.php
Как сделать, чтобы туда постоянно не добавлять(**как пример**)

```
if ($_GET['edit_news'])
{
  // тут мы редактируем\добавляем новости
}
if ($_GET['edit_articles'])
{
  // тут мы редактируем\добавляем статьи
}
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при запросе, например $_GET['content_type_method']
использовался определенный метод класса, который отвечает за сохранение, чтобы не копипастить одно и то же по сути?

Т.е. как-то так, образно конечно.

```
$className = 'class_'.$_GET['content_class'];
$anyClass = new $className();

$classMethod = $_GET['content_type_method'];
$anyClass->$classMethod($_POST);
```

Нормальная ли такая практика? Или как лучше?

Надеюсь корректно сформулировал вопрос.

Буду благодарен за советы и помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямо искать класс подставляя параметр из `$_GET` точно не стоит. Надо, как минимум, перед этим проверить, разрешено ли обращение к такому классу, т.е. что-то вроде:

```
if (!in_array($_GET['content_class'], $allowedClassesArray)) 
{ /* 404 */ }
```

Само собой, этот массив надо будет заполнить именами разрешенных классов.

Также стоит проверять, существует ли запрашиваемый метод и одолжить у фреймворков их способ именования методов, общающихся с пользователем - называть методы как `action<Name>`(), например, и добавить проверку на отсутствие такого метода:

```
$methodName = 'action'.$_GET['content_type_method'];

if (!method_exists($anyClass, $methodName)
{ /* 404 */ }
```

После этого, в принципе, можете вызывать данный метод и работать.

*UPD: можно применить второе решение и к созданию класса, т.е. принять какой-то свой стандарт именования для контроллеров и считать их разрешенными для обращения.*

Comment: Спасибо.

Проверять конечно надо как класс, так и метод.

У меня классы отвечающие за контент лежат в одной папке. И файлы имеют одинаковые названия с названием класса. Т.е. можно просто прочитать директорию и на основе результата забить массив с названиями, отрезав все лишнее.
Я как раз хочу избежать ручной работы и по максимуму автоматизировать все. Понятно, что добавить что-то в массив не сложно. Но если можно этого не делать))...

Comment: можно фреймворк использовать :) тогда всю эту рутину по маршрутизации он будет на себя брать, а девелопер описывает только марзруты и экшены в контроллерах, код получается чисты, красивый и безопасный :)

Comment: ох. это переделывать нужно будет очень много.
Я искал какой-то мелкий(именно мелкий, да же чисто простую и удобную систему роутов), чтобы работал с php5.2(5,3 не понимаю много чего), чтобы система роутов была проста и понятна. но пока ничего для себя не нашел.

Comment: берется книжка, например http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/ и через пару дней приходит понимание пхп 5.3, затем изучается за пару часов composer, а далее роуты можно взять от сюда: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/introduction.html

Comment: @drop_off, я вам предложил направление, а уж как заполнять массив - ваше дело. Фреймворк, как советует @digi, это очень хорошее решение, которое избавит вас от необходимости писать такие велосипеды.

Comment: В крупных фреймворках я не разберусь с ходу. Люди их месяцами(годами) изучают. А учесть, что знания у меня на начальном уровне, то это будет просто жесть))) Тем более, над проектом надо сейчас работать.
По этому пока изобретаю велосипеды(кто этого не делал?))

Comment: на изучение фв надо потратить время, но используя полученные навыки, дальше это время с лихвой компенсируется... на написание велика тоже нужно время, но в последующем велики практически непригодны для повторного использования, по этому есть смысл брать и начинать изучать фв уже сейчас, а не ждать "лучших времен" ;)) фв разумеется Symfony2.

Comment: @digi, это была шутка, да?)) Symfony человеку, у которого знания на начальном уровне? Чтобы он больше никогда не смог стать прежним? :)  
@drop_off, само собой, надо разобраться в ООП, чтобы использовать какой-то фреймворк и понимать его работу. То, что проект надо писать уже сейчас пугает.. но дело ваше.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашаясь с тов. [[@xEdelweiss](/users/7017/xedelweiss)](/users/7017/xedelweiss), добавлю.

Я делал такой класс

```
class mail
    {

    function box_save($box, $register_owner = false)
        {
        // some code here
        return $box;    // array
        }

    function box_user($id_or_address, $user = NULL, $ignore_owner = false)
        {
        ...
        return ($box) ? true : false;   // bool
        }
    ...
    }
```

Позже я решил допилить HTTP-API (для AJAX-а, да). И тоже сначала думал пихать первым аргументом массив, а внутри метода проверять: если это массив, то распаковывать его. Но, ведь, аргументом может действительно быть массив. Решил сделать обертку в виде особого класса для передачи аргументов. После этого просто дописал один метод в класс `mail` и дописал одну строку в начале каждого метода, который я планировал «экспортировать». Мой класс `mail` стал выглядеть так:

```
class mail
    {

    private function args($args_0 = NULL)
        {
        $args_0 = $args_0[0];
        if ((is_object($args_0)) && (is_a($args_0, 'args_wrapper')))
            $res = $args_0->all();
            else
            $res = array();

        return $res;
        }

    function box_save($box, $register_owner = false)
        {
        extract($this->args(func_get_args()));
        // some code here
        return $box;    // array
        }

    function box_user($id_or_address, $user = NULL, $ignore_owner = false)
        {
        extract($this->args(func_get_args()));
        ...
        return ($box) ? true : false;   // bool
        }
    ...
    }
```

И добавил сам класс args_wrapper:

```
    class args_wrapper
        {
        private $args = array();

        function __construct()
            {
            $args = func_get_args();

            for ($i = count($args) - 1; $i > -1; $i--)
                {
                if (is_array($args[$i]))
                    {
                    $this->args = array_merge($this->args, $args[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }

        function __get($name)
            {
            return (isset($this->args[$name])) ? $this->args[$name] : NULL;
            }

        function __set($name, $value)
            {
            $this->args[$name] = $value;
            return $value;
            }

        function all()
            {
            return $this->args;
            }

        function __invoke($callable)
            {
            if (!is_callable($callable))
                {
                trigger_error('$callable isn`t callable. Return NULL.', E_USER_WARNING);
                return NULL;
                } else
                {
                return call_user_func($callable, $this);
                }
            }
        }
```

После этого осталось только добавить обработку запросов с возможностью передачи GET/POST параметров. Я сделал файлец api.php:

```
$args = new notes_args_wrapper($_REQUEST);
$mail = new mail();

$method = 'box_save';
// на самом деле, конечно, вызываемый метод определяется иначе:
// я его определяю по REQUEST_URI

$res = call_user_func(array($mail, $method), $args);
// здесь могло быть: $res = $args(array($mail, $method));

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8', true, 200);
die(json_encode($res));
```

После всего этого я мог смело вызывать `/api.php?box[id]=1&box[password]=12345678&register_owner=1`, что приводило к вызову метода `mail::box_save`, в котором аргументы распаковывались в переменные:

```
$box = array(
    'id' => "1",
    'password' => "12345678"
    );

$register_owner = "1";
```

А получал я в ответ JSON, с которым оперировал уже на стороне клиента.

Ну и при всем этом я мог пользоваться этим же классом, передавая методам аргументы традиционным способом. Получилось довольно вкусно. Но есть и минус в виде спада производительности: вся эта магия, да и вообще вызов функции/метода — длительная операция.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую.